# What's different between Arraylist and Arrayadapter

Tags: arraylist

look at this code and tell if i use 
Arraylist whats happen ..i want to know whats a diffrent between ArrayList and Arrayadaptor?

```
public class structNote {
    public String  title;
    public String  description;
    public boolean done;
}

public class AdapteNote extends ArrayAdapter<structNote> {
    public AdapteNote(ArrayList<structNote> array) {
    super(G.context, R.layout.adaptornote, array);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ArrayList** is list which holds list of int, String...

**ArrayAdapter** is `adapter`, which is used for Listing items in screen, like for ListView. It has more functions for that, if item removed in background, `ArrayAdapter` will remove it as well if you call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`, it updates screen.  You can not use ArrayList as `adapter` for Listing items on screen, but you can use it for holding list of items in memory.

Picture below `ArrayAdapter` holds `items` inside `ListView`. You can not use `ArrayList` for such listing.

[image]

Comment: tnx for your answer ..my friend